# Recent view Product block in Product page from Extention

Tags: products

I'm new user of magento, I'm developing a ecommerse website www.zinzzy.com, I want to show recent viewed product for same user visited these product in product page as Myntra.com. i have installed atwix recent view product bar extension,that are showing at bottom bar after visiting product page on website.

I want to show these recent view products block in product page only. Have any option to show recent view block in product page.

Please help me any one. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Why install a extension when Magento does this out of the box?

Answer (score 1):

Shrikant,

If you look at the layout update file for the module most likely there will be a section that is defining the block as a child of another.  If that is the case then you can implement the same logic for the product page layout and call it there with getChildHtml('block_name').

Take a sample from the catalog.xml of the base/default magento theme.

In this node:
`<catalog_product_view translate="label">` you will find `<reference name="content">` and in there you will find the `<block type="catalog/product_view_media" name="product.info.media" as="media" template="catalog/product/view/media.phtml"/>` declaration.  If you now go to  `catalog/product/view.phtml` you will see something like `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('media') ?>`.

By the same method you can define the recently viewed products to be used on the product display page.

Most likely you will need to format the display but it should get you in the right direction.

If it currently displays other places, then in that layout xml you can remove the definitions or in the templates that it is called from you can remove the calls.

Hope this helps.
Thanks

Comment: Thanx for response, i've solved it

Comment: yes you have define me right solution, its work for me, great, Thank you very much